# how to style Server templates in meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, server

I have a file in my /private folder which I then use for SSR.compileTemplate and SSR.render to send nice html verification email; is it possible to style it with bootstrap as well? if so where I should put the real client-like template file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its for email template you will need inline styles in order to make it work with most of the email services, so you just use a css inliner(like this one http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html).

Another problem you might find is that some features don't work, like media queries, so its possible that your bootstrap styles don't look as you wanted.

I recommend you to use the zurb foundation emails, It has great compatibility with most of the email clients http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

Comment: thank you I will have a look; my inline styling worked but I wanted to have it nicely organised in line with my app colors

Comment: You can have a master file html and css, that you modify, and have a "compiled one" that has been inlined with the inliner, that allows you to easily modify the master files without having to care about the inline styles.